# 2-dimensional manifold is orientable if and only if it does not contain the Möbius band

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, mobius-band, non-orientable-surfaces

Criterion for non-orientability: a manifold $M$ is non-orientable if and only if it contains a "bad" sequence of charts, i.e. $\{U_i,\varphi_i\},i=1,\ldots,n$ such that the transition maps $\varphi_{i+1}\circ\varphi_i^{-1},i=1,\ldots,n-1$ all have positive Jacobian determinant, and $\varphi_1\circ\varphi_n^{-1}$ has negative Jacobian determinant at some point $x\in\varphi_1(U_1\cap U_n)$. The Möbius band is non-orientable. So, one part of the question is clear: given that $M$ is orientable, suppose that it contains the Möbius band. Then in the Möbius band there's a "bad" sequence of charts. Then it's also such a sequence in $M$, so it is non-orientable; a contradiction. My question is about the converse. Given that there's no Möbius band within $M$, suppose $M$ is non-orientable. In order to arrive at a contradiction, we'd have to construct a Möbius band in $M$. How do I approach this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The criterion you mention is not a criterion for non-orientability.  For example, $S^2$ is covered by two charts $U_1$ and $U_2$ where $U_1$ consists of everything except the north pole, and $U_2$ is everything but the south pole.  If you let $\phi_i:U_i\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be the usual stereographic projections, and let $r:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a reflection, then $r\circ \phi_2$ is  still a chart map and $(r\circ \phi_2)\circ \phi_1^{-1}$ has negative Jacobian.

Comment: You should put $2$-dimensional manifold in the body of your text. ... Jason's point is a good one, but to your original question — there must be an orientation-reversing embedded circle. (Why?) How can you use this?

Comment: @JasonDeVito: For negative being of Jacobian you have computed the Jacobian of that map directly  or you are arguing just topologically or it is easy to see??

Comment: And you are saying that "orientable iff not contain the Möbius band" is wrong?

Comment: @JasonDeVito I added some clarification in the question. But regarding your example: $S^2$ is orientable, and if we had two charts, and one transition map had negative Jacobian, then the other transition would be just the inverse of the first, so it would also have negative Jacobian. My criterion is that if we had positive Jacobian transition everywhere except one point in one pair of charts.

Comment: @TedShifrin Could you clarify what an orientation-reversing circle is?

Comment: @element:  I apparently misread your criterion, sorry about that.  As penance, I'll spend some time thinking about your question and see if I can supply a response ;-)

Comment: @C.F.G:  I didn't not compute that Jacobian - in fact, maybe a better way of phrasing my first comment is that either $\phi_2\circ \phi^{-1}$ has negative Jacobian or $(r\circ \phi_2)\circ \phi_1^{-1}$ does.  This claim *is* obvious because reflections reverse orientation.  I had assumed it was the second option without thinking about it.  And I agree that "orientable iff not contain the Möbius band" is correct for *surfaces*.

Comment: @TedShifrin:  How exactly does one construct the orientation reversing circle?  The obvious guess is to pick points $p_0\in U_1\cap U_n)$, $p_i\in U_i\cap U_{i+1}$ and connect $p_0$ to $p_1$ to $p_2$.... to $p_{n-1}$ to $p_0$ and then smooth out corners.   But how do you necessarily avoid self intersections?  I know how to deal with finitely many, but how do you assure there are only finitely many?

Comment: @Jason: I guess the way I usually think about this, there's only one corner to round. I fix $p$ and take smooth paths from $p$ to $q$. There must be some choice of $q$ and paths where propagating the orientation from $p$ to $q$ along the two paths gives opposite results. Now I can round the corner at $q$.

Comment: @TedShifrin:  I see.  If the resulting curve has no self intersections, then its normal bundle gives the Möbius band the OP wants.  If there are self intersections, then this doesn't quite work.  If there are finite number of self intersections, one can first nudge the curve so these intersections are transverse, and so they locally look like the letter $x$.  Separating this into either $><$ or $\vee \wedge$ (with $\vee$ on top of $\wedge$) will give a connected graph with one less crossing.  I'm less clear what to do if there are an infinite number of self intersections. (continued)

Comment: I know how to deal with the "infinitely many crossing" cases either using a background Riemannian metric (then picking piecewise geodesics for the curve), or via transversality arguments, but I don't know how to do it with the tools the OP seems to be using.  Is there some easy to way achieve finitely many intersection points, e.g., by using slice coordinates about the embedded portions of the curve?

Comment: @Jason: You're making this too hard. By a straightforward connectedness argument, you can join any two points by an embedded path (easy in the topological setting, and, smoothing corners, not much harder in the smooth category). I believe. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin:  I agree that in a connected manifold it's not too hard to construct a smooth embedding of $[0,1]$ which connects one point to another.  But if I'm understanding your construction, you need two such paths, so that their concatenation gives you the closed curve.  Creating the second is easy if $M$ with first path removed is still connected.  And it is connected, say, as a consequence of Alexander duality.  But the the first curve is smoothly embedded, there is likely a much simpler argument.  Anyway, sorry to hijack the thread.  I am ok with dropping it if you are ;-)

Comment: @Jason: I see how to guarantee the paths are disjoint away from the endpoints with an elementary argument, but I agree that we have hijacked enough.